# Output result in a new Window

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically, I have a root window that has a couple of buttons that runs different Python code, and it outputs the result into the console.

Is there a way to display the output into a new window (pop-up window) once the user clicks the button?

Comment: Have you asked google anything? Even, searches like "python tkinter pop-up" should point you to the right direction.

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by "runs different Python code" and "it outputs the result". How do you run the code? How does it do the output? Also, do you know how to create an instance of `Toplevel`?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a message box by doing
The Imports:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import ttk
```

Heres the Code:

```
window = Tkinter.Tk()
    window.wm_withdraw()

    #centre screen message
    window.geometry("1x1+"+str(window.winfo_screenwidth()/2)
                    +"+"+str(window.winfo_screenheight()/2))
    tkMessageBox.showinfo(title=" ", message=" ")
```